# How to extract a PEM key from a PFX file?

Tags: python, adobe, pem

I have created a certificate with Adobe Reader and saved it to the hard disk. Now, I would like to extract the PEM key in order to create a digital signature for other PDF files using a different program not mentioned here

```
import PyPDF2
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import SHA256
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12 import load_key_and_certificates

def pfxToPem():
    # Load the pfx file
    certificato_pfx = 'Nome.pfx'
    password = 'aaaaa'

    with open(certificato_pfx, 'rb') as pfx_file:
        pfx_data = pfx_file.read()

    # Extracts key and certificate
    private_key, certificate, additional_certificates = load_key_and_certificates(pfx_data, password.encode('utf-8'))

    # Serialize key 
    private_key_pem = private_key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
    )

    # Save to file 
    with open('chiave.pem', 'wb') as key_file:
        key_file.write(private_key_pem)
```

return message :

`CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Parsed a negative serial number, which is disallowed by RFC 5280.` 
Is there an error in the code?
Why am I receiving this message even though the certificate was created by a reputable software like Adobe ?
Do I need to manually change the serial number?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this might be useful.

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import pkcs12, Encoding, PrivateFormat, NoEncryption

with open('Nome.pfx', 'rb') as in_file:
    pfx = pkcs12.load_pkcs12(in_file.read(), b'aaaaa')

pvt = pfx.key.private_bytes(Encoding.PEM, PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL, NoEncryption())
cert = pfx.cert.certificate.public_bytes(Encoding.PEM)
if pfx.additional_certs:
    for _cert in a.additional_certs:
        _cert.certificate.public_bytes(Encoding.PEM)
```

You can either write the key and certificate to a file to use the loaded key for further use.